# Using Woo commerce and Paypal payments are received in my Paypal account, but it doesn't register in Woo and the orders eventually time out

Tags: woocommerce, paypal

This is the message that shows up in Woo about the order:

"Unpaid order cancelled – time limit reached. Order status changed from Pending payment to Cancelled."

Even though the money does get deposited into the Paypal account it doesn't register back into Woo.

I've had the same setup for years and it has worked fine...just started doing this about a month ago?

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Comment: Review your PayPal account's IPN history at https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history

Comment: Thanks Preston.  I have been doing that (only way that I know they actually paid)  the problem is, the communication from Paypal back to Woo after the payment gets deposited.  It doesn't register as paid so the order "times out" and gets cancelled in my Woo Commerce.

Comment: What does the IPN history show?

Comment: Sorry for the delay Preston. I was on vacation.   Also, I actually wasn't doing that...I was just on the activity page.  On the IPN history it just shows as "retrying" on the status.  Also, I did a refund in Woo and it never registered back into Paypal.   Any ideas?

Comment: Retrying means the IPN message is not being received or processed successfully by WooCommerce.  What is the HTTP status that shows in IPN history for these retrying messages? 500? 404? 403? Your WooCommerce endpoint is returning that status. Find out why. This problem needs to be troubleshooted on the WooCommerce end, by a developer familiar with it.